# How to extend lifetime for variable handed over to tokio spawned co-routine

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm using `tokio` to create a new thread to execute a task on file paths found using [walkdir](https://docs.rs/walkdir/latest/walkdir/). It basically looks like follows:

```
    pub async fn hash_tree(start_path: &Path) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        for entry in WalkDir::new(start_path) {
            let file_path_entry = entry.unwrap();
            let file_path = file_path_entry.path();
    
            let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
                hashing::hash_file(file_path).await.unwrap();
            });
        }
```

The problem with this code is that the file path doesn't live long enough. Rust fails with:

```
error[E0597]: `file_path_entry` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:44:25
   |
44 |         let file_path = file_path_entry.path();
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                         |
   |                         borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                         argument requires that `file_path_entry` is borrowed for `'static`
...
61 |     }
   |     - `file_path_entry` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I understand the issue but I'm not sure how to tackle it. Would it be better to first gather all the `file_path`s in a vector and then push them into co-routines? I would rather prefer to kick the spawned task off as soon as it is found. Can I alternatively push copies of the `file_path`s to a vector that is owned by the outer scope so that I can make sure that they live long enough (EDIT: tried `push`ing the paths onto a vector with greater scope but that didn't work either)?

What would be alternative/better ways to handle that?

Comment: you can move a clone of the variable, so the corrutine will take ownership of it `hashing::hash_file(file_path.clone()).await.unwrap();`

Comment: Or move the direntry (`file_path_entry`) itself instead of moving the (borrowed) path. Or create the path via `into_path` (which consumes the direntry). `.path()` is just `&self.path` internally, it's not a costly or complex operation.

Comment: "Can I alternatively push copies of the file_paths to a vector that is owned by the outer scope so that I can make sure that they live long enough (EDIT: tried pushing the paths onto a vector with greater scope but that didn't work either)?" tasks are not scoped / lexical, so as far as the compiler is concerned they can outlive their ancestor. A way to fix this would be to use *futures* rather than tasks, though it would serialize the actual (CPU-heavy I assume) hashing bits whereas `spawn` can fan them out over the tokio workers if you use the default multi-threaded runtime.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to include the solution. Instead you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Netwave and Masklinn! What finally worked was moving a clone of `file_path_entry.clone()`. As Masklinn pointed out, `path` is also borrowed. So, this works:

```
for entry in WalkDir::new(start_path).follow_links(false) {
    let file_path_entry = entry.unwrap();
    let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        hashing::hash_file(file_path_entry.clone()).await.unwrap();
    });
```